# Crear una tabla temporal que me almacene una consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas soy nuevo en SQl necesito que la consulta que estoy realizando se almacene
en una tabla temporal como puedo hacer. Esta es la consulta

```
SELECT H.[id_hi],
       H.[int_anoot],
       H.[int_consecutivoot],
       H.[fk_tm],
       IETM.[vrc_nombretm],
       (SELECT IETM.[vrc_nombretm]
        WHERE  IETM.[vrc_nombretm] = 'preventivo') AS TA_PREV,
       (SELECT IETM.[vrc_nombretm]
        WHERE  IETM.[vrc_nombretm] = 'correctivo') AS TA_CORR,
       (SELECT IETM.[vrc_nombretm]
        WHERE  IETM.[vrc_nombretm] <> 'correctivo'
               AND IETM.[vrc_nombretm] <> 'preventivo'
               AND IETM.[vrc_nombretm] <> 'otro')  AS TA_O_Mto,
       (SELECT IETM.[vrc_nombretm]
        WHERE  IETM.[vrc_nombretm] = 'otro')       AS TA_Otro,
       (SELECT H.[bit_nombrett1]
        WHERE  H.[bit_nombrett1] = 1)              AS T_MEC,
       (SELECT H.[bit_nombrett2]
        WHERE  H.[bit_nombrett2] = 1)              AS T_ELEC,
       (SELECT H.[bit_nombrett3]
        WHERE  H.[bit_nombrett3] = 1)              AS T_INS_ELEC,
       (SELECT H.[bit_nombrett4]
        WHERE  H.[bit_nombrett4] = 1)              AS T_OTRO,
       H.[int_tiempoduraciondias]                  AS TDISD,
       H.[int_tiempoduracionhoras]                 AS THORD,
       H.[int_tiempoduracionminutos]               AS TMIND,
       H.[int_tiempoimproductivodias]              AS TDIAI,
       H.[int_tiempoimproductivohoras]             AS THORI,
       H.[int_tiempoimproductivominutos]           AS TMINI,
       IES.[vrc_clsabreviatura]                    AS ESTADO,
       GMOHI.[int_numhorashombre_grmo]             AS HH_MO_HI,
       GMOHI.[int_numminutos_grmo]                 AS MH_MO_HI,
       GMOHI.[int_tipohora]                        AS TIPO_MO_HI,
       GMOHI.[mny_valorhora_grmo]                  AS VALOR_HH_HI
FROM   [dbo].[tbl_hi] H
       LEFT JOIN [tbl_ie_tipo_mantenimiento] IETM
              ON H.[fk_tm] = IETM.[id_tm]
       LEFT JOIN [tbl_ie_estados] IES
              ON H.[fk_es] = IES.[id_es]
       LEFT JOIN [tbl_hi_gastoreal_manoobra] AS GMOHI
              ON H.[id_hi] = GMOHI.[fk_hi]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intentas hacer el select directo a la tabla temporal?

Comment: si, intento que todos esos datos me queden en una tabla temporal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen dos tipo de tablas temporales. Una se guarda en disco (en concreto en la base de datos TempDB) y la otra en memoria, como una variable más. Esta última es la preferida cuando la tabla no debe tener muchos datos.

La primera se crea como una tabla normal, pero con el signo `#` delante. La crearíamos así:

```
CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal (Campo1 int, campo2 varchar(50), ...)
```

y luego podemos insertar lo que queramos en ella como en cualquier otra tabla.

La segunda se define como un tipo `table` y se crea de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @TablaTemporal table (Campo1 int, campo2 varchar(50), ...)
```

Una vez creada puede insertar los datos:

```
INSERT INTO @TablaTemporal (Campo1, Campo2, ...)
SELECT Campo1, Campo2, ...
FROM TuTabla

INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal (Campo1, Campo2, ...)
SELECT Campo1, Campo2, ...
FROM TuTabla
```

y recoger el resultado

```
SELECT *
FROM @TablaTemporal

SELECT *
FROM #TablaTemporal
```

**EDITO la respuesta**

Aunque existe la posibilidad de disponer de una tabla temporal para todas las sesiones (en vez de `#` se utiliza `##`), puede que la mejor opción sea poner la consulta en una [función](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) que devuelva su contenido, esto tiene la ventaja de que es posible enviar parámetros a la función.
Sería algo así:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TablaGlobal ()
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN   
(  
    SELECT P.ProductID, P.Name, SUM(SD.LineTotal) AS 'Total'  
    FROM Production.Product AS P
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SD ON SD.ProductID = P.ProductID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SH ON SH.SalesOrderID = SD.SalesOrderID
    JOIN Sales.Customer AS C ON SH.CustomerID = C.CustomerID  
    WHERE C.StoreID = @storeid  
    GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.Name  
);
```

y luego la llamarías así:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TablaGlobal()
```

La desventaja de una función y de una vista es que son de solo lectura.

Comment: Ojo.. OP no quiere hacer un insert.. quiere hacer un select a la tabla temporal...

Comment: el problema que tengo es que estos datos vienen de varias tablas y tienen cambios  entonces no se como definir el FROM o como puedo hacer que tome los datos de las tablas, adicional no vienen tal cual estoy en el select creando campos. Hay alguna documentación que me recomienden para esto, he buscado pero no encuentro nada que me sirva. P.D Adicional de lo que dice que no lo haga, pero en este caso no es una opción, el jefe quiere esa tabla a pesar de mis múltiples objeciones y debe ser de tipo golbal por lo que he leido. Gracias

Comment: @juandavidzambrano he editado la respuesta con otra posibilidad.

Comment: Buenas una pregunta por que cuando escribo eso en sql server 2016, me sale " 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'." De entrada me marca CREATE FUNCTION COMO ERROR

Comment: Fíjate que no te falte nada, paréntesis, etc. Empieza por una de simple y luego la modificas, por ejemplo `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TablaGlobal ()
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN   
(  
    SELECT getdate() as fecha
)`

Comment: GRACIAS, YA LO PASA, VAMOS A VER COMO ME VA LLEVANDO TODO EL SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un SELECT INTO para crear la definición de la tabla temporal y posteriormente hacerle select como quieres.

Por otro lado, en lugar de crear una tabla temporal podrias crear una vista basado en la consulta que elaboraste para consultarla y filtrarla según la necesidad que tengas.

Para mas documentación mira:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15